# get second max element in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an array,  say `A = [ 3 5 6 7 ]`. I know I can get the maximum value of this array with `max(A)` and it returns `7`, but how can I get the second max (`6`)  from this array without sorting or removing the first maximum value?

Comment: what is your concern about sorting? I ask this because it is possible you are prematurely trying to optimise. Always look only for the crucial bottleneck of your program if it is slow.

Comment: because of changing indices :(.

Comment: see the update in my answer for that

Comment: sorry, I didn't get the sort thing. Writing out the explicit algorithm is pretty easy, you know, right? My guess is that the explicit algorithm will be slower than matlab core function, though.

Comment: So, I have a guess. You can have linear, 1-pass, iterative solution; that's easy to do. Or core-function linear 3-pass solution (Barnaba's one, which is undoubtedly faster than sorting based solution, and probably faster than 1-pass iterative). Are you still looking for anything better?

Comment: btw I am not sure matlab would actually do a full sort if the majority of the returned index values are never accessed. But it looks for me like the OP only had a confusion using sort, and this was a typical [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can propose following tricky solution:

```
second_max_value = max(A(A~=max(A)))
```

Here `A(A~=max(A))` will be temporary array that not contain maximal value of original array. Than you receive maximum of this array.

Comment: Yes, but this one actually creates a copy of A, skipping the max value. (If matlab doesn't optimise it away.)

Answer (score 7):

First of all, unless you have really-really large vectors, use unique and get the second last index.

If you wish to preserve the max element and you vector does not contain NaN's you can try:

```
[max_value,max_idx] = max(A);  % [3 5 6 7]
A(idx) = NaN;              % [3 5 6 NaN]
second_max_value = max(A); % 6
A(idx) = max_value;        % [3 5 6 7]
```

If you have multiple indices with the same max value, it is your choice to include

```
if length(max_idx)>1, second_max_value=max_value, end
```

**UPDATE:**

According to the comment of the OP next to the question, let me add:

You can also use sort **without** changing the original array:

```
[~, idx] = sort(A);
A(idx(end)) % is the max value
A(idx(end-1)) % is the second max value
```

Comment: I mentioned in my question with out remove first max element. :(. hoever tnx for your attenction

Comment: Np, my code does not remove the max element but overwrites it. Hence it is an in-place operation, if you'd concern about the linearity and memory consumption of the solution.

Comment: Can you please check the update addressing your concerns about using `sort`?

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
        B = unique(A);      % // Finds unique values and sorts
        max_2 = B(end-1);   % // Second maximum
```

?

test:

```
     A= [ 3 5 6 7  2 4]
     B = unique(A)
     B(end-1)

        ans =

            6
```